# Server Side Scripting not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

[image]I am new to MVC and creating a sample application by viewing [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-UdqWy9lVc&feature=youtu.be&hd=1) video.I have created a class in Model and a controller.Now when i try to access Class property through view,i am not able to access it,even when i am writing in view like <%=Model.Id %>,the angular brackets are not yellow marked as in case of server side scripting.I am not able to find where the problem is?

Class Customer in Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcCustomer.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string  Name { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and Controller is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcCustomer.Models;

namespace MvcCustomer.Controllers
{
    public class LoadCustomerAndDisplayController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /LoadCustomerAndDisplay/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.Name = "Devesh";
            customer.Amount = 22.9;
            customer.Id = 1;

            return View(customer);
        }

    }
}
```

and my strongly typed view(IntelliSense is also not working) is

```
@model MvcCustomer.Models.Customer

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        The Customer id is: <%= Model.Id %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your Solution Explorer?

Comment: @DanielA.White i have added screenshot

Comment: Why -1?I am new to MVC framework and don't have understanding about Razor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is coded with Razor.

To initiate server side behavior use `@`, not `<%= ... %>`

Have a look here.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're using a Razor view, not an ASP.NET view, so the syntax is `@Model.Id` *not* `<%= Model.Id %>`.